# how can I save the value from a select element in custom config field in magento2

Tags: magento2, configuration, renderer

I'm trying to add a custom configuration field in system.xml like this where one of the columns will be a select element instead of a simple input element and will load values dynamically from the database.

[image]

Afterwards I want to save the serialized value in the database.

By reading the various tutorials online I understand that I have to actually create a custom field and create the custom frontend_model and backend_model

So I am trying with the following relevant parts of code which create the interface I want

`system.xml`

```
            <field id="availability_map" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
                <label>Availability Map</label>
                <frontend_model>Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\AvailabilityMap</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>Namespace\Module\Config\Backend\AvailabilityMap</backend_model>
            </field>
```

Then I utilize the `Select` element class to render my option array in the first column.

`Field/AvailabilityMap.php`

```
class AvailabilityMap extends AbstractFieldArray{

    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $availabilityAttributeCode = $this->defaultHelper->getPartialConfig('stock/availability_attribute');
        $this->productAttributeOption->setAttributeCode($availabilityAttributeCode);
        $options = $this->productAttributeOption->toOptionArray();

        $attributeOptionRenderer = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(Select::class)
        ;
        $attributeOptionRenderer->setOptions($options);
        $this->addColumn('availability_option', [
            'label' => __('Availability Option'),
            'renderer' => $attributeOptionRenderer,
        ]);
        $this->addColumn('custom_availability_option', ['label' => __('Custom Availability Option'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add Correlation');
    }
}
```

But I'm unable to save the values correctly. I tried this in my backend_model

`Backend/AvailabilityMap.php`

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value as ConfigValue;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

class AvailabilityMap extends ConfigValue
{
    /**
     * Json Serializer
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface
     */
    protected $serializer;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config, \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList, SerializerInterface $serializer, ?\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null, ?\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Prepare data before save
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        /** @var array $value */
        $value = $this->getValue();
        unset($value['__empty']);
        $encodedValue = $this->serializer->serialize($value);

        $this->setValue($encodedValue);
    }

    /**
     * Process data after load
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        /** @var string $value */
        $value = $this->getValue();
        if(empty($value)){
            $this->setValue(null);
        }
        else{
            $decodedValue = $this->serializer->unserialize($value);
            $this->setValue($decodedValue);
        }
    }


}
```

And the final result only saves the text input. I'm probably missing something in the way to transform the submitted data to the array I need to save.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change backend model.

```
<backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
```

**OR**

Extend backend model from

> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized

**[Update]**

I tried following way:

```
<field id="availability_map" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
    <label>Availability Map</label>
    <frontend_model>SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\AvailabilityMap</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
</field>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/AvailabilityMap.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
use \Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class AvailabilityMap extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    protected $optionField;

    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('availability_option', [
            'label' => __('Availability Option'),
            'renderer' => $this->getOptionField(),
        ]);
        $this->addColumn('custom_availability_option', ['label' => __('Custom Availability Option'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add Correlation');
    }

    /**
     * @return \SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\OptionField
     */
    protected function getOptionField()
    {
        if (!$this->optionField) {
            $this->optionField = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                OptionField::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }

        return $this->optionField;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare existing row data object
     *
     * @param DataObject $row
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _prepareArrayRow(DataObject $row)
    {
        $availabilityOption = $row->getAvailabilityOption();
        $options = [];
        if ($availabilityOption) {
            $options['option_' . $this->getOptionField()->calcOptionHash($availabilityOption)]
                = 'selected="selected"';
        }
        $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
    }
}
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/OptionField.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select;

class OptionField extends Select
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->getOptions()) {

            $options = [
                [
                    'value' => 1,
                    'label' => 'Option 1'
                ],
                [
                    'value' => 2,
                    'label' => 'Option 2'
                ],
                [
                    'value' => 3,
                    'label' => 'Option 3'
                ]
            ];
            $this->setOptions($options);
        }

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Sets name for input element
     *
     * @param string $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setInputName($value)
    {
        return $this->setName($value);
    }
}
```

Here is the output after edit:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried both ways you mentioned and I have the same result. Only the second column is saved in the database. That's why I'm experimenting with creating my own backend_model for this

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: So basically I was missing two steps as I understand it. 1) Extend the `Select` element instead of using the original class directly because it's missing the setInputName function so that the value can actually be stored in the db and 2) to extend the `_prepareArrayRow` so that I can preselect the saved option when loading the table. Thank you very much, your example helped me experiment and work through my issue by stepping around the various functions.

Comment: @SohelRana I am using https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/dynamic-row-system-config.html and it is working fine but is is saving in database like  `{"_1611313526052_52":{"from_qty":"0","to_qty":"10","price":"5","tax":"1"},"_1611313539134_134":{"from_qty":"11","to_qty":"20","price":"4","tax":"1"}}`. How to save like {"from_qty":"0","to_qty":"10","price":"5","tax":"1"}

Comment: it's works for me. thank you