# How to create a table in configuration system.xml file in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, system.xml, table

How can i create table in system.xml file is there any way? I had searched around but can't find any solution
[image]

want to create like this

Comment: You want to save data into your custom table, not in core_config_data?

Comment: no no not in my custom table

Comment: just want to show user fields like this

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: magento version 2.2.7

Comment: You can do it using `frontend_model`

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: Check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273331/how-can-i-save-the-value-from-a-select-element-in-custom-config-field-in-magento

Comment: i can't extend text field  more then the one by ths @sohel Rana

Comment: @AsadUllah
check please: https://gitlab.com/mageprashant/admin-system-configuration-table

Comment: same problem unable to save config. unable to press "save config" button @PrashantPatel

Comment: @AsadUllah
if you can change config column name then you can run below commands
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:s:d -f

Comment: **Unable to unserialize value.** gettng this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

In your `system.xml` file:

```
        <group id="your_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>My Label</label>             
            <field id="id_name" translate="label" sortOrder="410" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Sub Label</label>
                <frontend_model>NameSpace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\MyClass</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Backend\MyClass</backend_model>
            </field>
        </group>
```

Explanation:
`NameSpace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\MyClass` is responsible for showing you the table as you desire.
`NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Backend\MyClass` is responsible to fill the data or save the data.

Now:

`NameSpace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\MyClass.php`:

```
<?php 
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

class MyClass extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * Prepare to render
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('my_column', ['label' => __('Column 1')]);
        $this->addColumn('my_column_two', ['label' => __('Column 2')]);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add Tab');
    }
}
```

`NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Backend\MyClass.php`:

```
<?php 
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Backend;
class MyClass extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{
    
    /**
     * Process data after load
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        $arr = unserialize($value);

        $this->setValue($arr);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare data before save
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        unset($value['__empty']);
        $arr = serialize($value);
        
        $this->setValue($arr);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to the comments below, you may also use this:

`<backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>`

instead of

`<backend_model>NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Backend\MyClass</backend_model>`

Comment: It works in my instance. Which php are you using? Any error logs (browser console, system/log)?

Comment: Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 346 bytes in /var/www/m227/public_html/app/code/PME/STW/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/OptionField.php on line 16 "$arr = unserialize($value);" this line in backend

Comment: i am using php 7.0

Comment: That means, `$this->getValue();` is not giving you right value. You should log that value and check if the value is serializable.

Comment: ok now i think i am getting something can you please tell me how can i handle these values

Comment: `a:1:{s:17:"_1557297183024_24";a:2:{s:9:"my_column";s:3:"dsa";s:13:"my_column_two";s:3:"asd";}}` getting answer in this format

Comment: @AsadUllah you could find your error column in table "core_config_data" and set it to "NULL", it will solve your problem, but it will make your data lose. You can search by "path" column, and set "NULL" to the "value" column. I assume that your column is new and you will do anything to fix the issue. You can see my example here: http://i.imgur.com/sXSADYF.png

Comment: Also, @AsadUllah was right, we should use <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model> instead of custom <backend_model>

Answer (score 0):

After looking all files and errors this works for me combining two solutions in to one

`System.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="wheelslicing" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
        <label>Spin wheel slice</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="slicing" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Slice Setting</label>
        <tab>wheelslicing</tab>
        <resource>PME_STW::helloworld_config</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>General Configuration</label>

                <field id="slice1" translate="label" type="text"
                       sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Display Text</label>
                    <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
                </field>
                 <field id="slice2" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                        <label>Display Text</label>
                        <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
                    </field>
                 <field id="slice3" translate="label" type="text"
                    sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Display Text</label>
                    <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
                 </field>

            <field id="availability_map" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
                <label>Availability Map</label>
                <frontend_model>PME\STW\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\AvailabilityMap</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
            </field>

        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

In `PME\STW\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\AvailabilityMap`

```
<?php
namespace PME\STW\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
use \Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class AvailabilityMap extends AbstractFieldArray
{
protected $optionField;



  protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
//        $this->addColumn('availability_option', [
//            'label' => __('Availability Option'),
//            'renderer' => $this->getOptionField(),
//        ]);
        $this->addColumn('custom_availability_option', ['label' => __('Wheel Slice Value'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->addColumn('custom_availability', ['label' => __('Reward'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add Correlation');
    }

    /**
     * @return \SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\OptionField
     */
    protected function getOptionField()
    {
        if (!$this->optionField) {
            $this->optionField = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                OptionField::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }

        return $this->optionField;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare existing row data object
     *
     * @param DataObject $row
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _prepareArrayRow(DataObject $row)
    {
        $availabilityOption = $row->getAvailabilityOption();
        $options = [];
        if ($availabilityOption) {
            $options['option_' . $this->getOptionField()->calcOptionHash($availabilityOption)]
                = 'selected="selected"';
        }
        $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
    }

}
```

In your `phtml file` you will get this in json form decode it and use as u like